# svn: is there a graphical tool to assist in merges?

Tags: svn, merge

(Before you say this is a duplicate of [Tools for SVN Merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218053/tools-for-svn-merging) or [Graphical representation of SVN branch/merge activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308/graphical-representation-of-svn-branch-merge-activity), please read....)

I need a graphical tool to assist in merging in svn. I don't mean *per-file* merging; I have Beyond Compare and it works nicely. I mean merging trees. What I would like to see is a 3-way source tree merge, that shows me which files are the same and which are different, and facilitates selecting whether to keep the working version, or version A, or version B, or a merged version of both.

I also need a way to stop svn from doing *any* automatic merges without letting me approve or disapprove of them.

Any suggestions?

---

**edit:** I'm imagining some tool that behind the scenes does a `svn merge --dry-run` and parses the results somehow, to tell you what svn's recommendations are.

Comment: With which version of SVN / TortoiseSVN etc. are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question about preventing automatic merges, there is a [TortoiseSVN recipe](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/241). It can be adapted for svn.exe using `--diff3-cmd` switch.

Comment: thanks... hmm, I don't mind it telling me that it thinks I should do X, but I just need to see it as a recommendation before I accept it.