# Rendering Subversion tree?

Tags: svn, diagram

Is there a program that lets me render the branches/tags/trunk structure of a Subversion repository and/or a subpart of it? I would prefer it to be controllable via terminal commands, as I want to integrate it inside a webservice or similar.

I am looking for something like (of course, without any annotations):

http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1361/5153278909_13cde87ca6_b.jpg

An alternative may be generating any intermediate format (e.g. GraphViz).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308/graphical-representation-of-svn-branch-merge-activity

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN has the Revision Graph feature - http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a console-based solution, as I want to integrate that kind of graphs in a webservice and generate them on the fly.

I have edited my original question to add that additional requirement. Thanks!